# Me gustaría saber exactamente por que la función max no me devuelve siempre el valor máximo de entre los que tengo en la siguiente función

Tags: python

Tengo un proyecto entregable en el que tengo que hacer una función la cual me muestre de todas las viviendas que tengo en un CSV , la cual es considerada mejor entre ellas, con el criterio siguiente: **la mejor vivienda** es aquella que tiene el precio por metro cuadrado más bajo de entre las consideradas como buenas compras.

Se supone que una compra es buena, cuando la relación entre el precio y la superficie de una compra es inferior al precio medio por metro cuadrado de la localidad.
El precio medio de cada localidad, viene dado por el diccionario 'precios'
Tengo ya hecha una función anteriormente que me hace una tupla con los precios y superficies y estoy intentando implementarla

```
def buena_compra(viviendas, localidades):
"""Devuelve la mejor vivienda de entre las viviendas de las localidades que se pasan como parámetro.
La mejor vivienda, es aquella que tiene el precio por metro cuadrado más bajo de entre
las consideradas como buenas compras.
Se supone que una compra es buena, cuando la relación entre el precio y la superficie de una compra
es inferior al precio medio por metro cuadrado de la localidad. 
El precio medio de cada localidad, viene dado por el diccionario 'precios'.

Args:
    viviendas (list[Vivienda]): Lista de viviendas.
    localidades (set[str]): Conjunto de localidades.

Returns:
    Vivienda: Mejor vivienda de entre las viviendas de las localidades que se pasan como parámetro.
"""
precios=dict()
for localidad in localidades:
    precios_sup_loc=precios_superficies(viviendas,localidad)
    for e in precios_sup_loc:
        precio_superficie=e[0]/e[1]
    filtro_precio_m2=[vivienda.precio/vivienda.superficie for vivienda in viviendas if vivienda.localidad==localidad]
    print(filtro_precio_m2)
    suma=sum(filtro_precio_m2)
    contador_viviendas=Counter([vivienda.localidad for vivienda in viviendas if vivienda.localidad==localidad ])
    media=suma/contador_viviendas[localidad]
    clave=localidad
    if clave not in precios:
        precios[clave]=media
    suma=0
    media=0    
precio_maximo_m2=min(filtro_precio_m2)
return [vivienda for vivienda in viviendas if precios[clave]<precio_superficie and vivienda.localidad==localidad and vivienda.precio/vivienda.superficie==precio_maximo_m2]
```

Entonces me gustaría saber por que ahí la función `max` no me funciona correctamente y me devuelve valores que no siempre son el máximo.
El conjunto que he hecho de prueba es en la siguiente función

```
def test_buena_compra(viviendas, localidades):
print("Probando buena_compra de las localidades 'Michaelshire', 'Spencerberg', 'Port Travismouth'")
print("----------------------------------")
print(buena_compra(viviendas,localidades))
```

La cual va dentro del main
`test_buena_compra(lectura,{'Michaelshire','Spencerberg','Port Travismouth'})`
Tambien uso otra funcion que es precios_superficies la cual es

```
def precios_superficies(viviendas, localidad):
""" Devuelve una lista de tuplas (precio, superficie) de las viviendas de la localidad que se
pasa como parámetro. Suponemos que los precios del dataset están en dólares. Queremos que los
precios estén en euros. Suponga que un dólar equivale a 1.01 euros.

Args:
    viviendas (list[Vivienda]): Lista de viviendas.
    localidad (str): Localidad.
Returns:
    list[tuple[float, int]]: lista de tuplas (precio, superficie) de las viviendas de la localidad que se pasa como parámetro.
"""
#Filtramos por localidad y devolvemos el precio de la vivienda(float) y su superficie(entero)
return[(float(vivienda.precio)*1.01,int(vivienda.superficie))for vivienda in viviendas if localidad==vivienda.localidad]
```

Comment: Bienvenido, @Alvaro . Edita la pregunta para corregir la identación. En los bucles estás sobreescibiendo las variables en cada iteración y no veo ningún `return` que devuelva el resultado. Además deberías usar `min` para obtener la mejor relación precio/superficie, no `max`. ¿Puedes añadir algún ejemplo de los resultados que obtienes?

Comment: claro por supuesto, voy a compartirte una captura de pantalla de todo, o si quieres puede compartirte el repositorio de github con el csv en cuestión

Comment: Créate un conjunto de prueba reducido con el que puedas jugar y mostrar en la pregunta. Dos localidades y 5 viviendas por localidad,p.e.

Comment: acabo de añadir mas informacion sobre el proyecto, ya que creo que no habia suficiente

Comment: El problema es que siempre me arroja una de las viviendas ,considerada como buenas viviendas,pero no tiene correlación alguna a que está sea la que tiene el menor precio por metro cuadrado ,que es lo que necesito para que sea la mejor de entre estas ,además siempre me arroja resultados sin congruencia alguna ,ya que supongo que sí coge los elementos del conjunto sin orden no lo estoy haciendo bien a la hora de añadir elementos etc

Comment: No veo que uses la función `max()` en ninguna parte.